# JUnit Test of Spreadsheet using Apache POI

Tags: junit, apache-poi

I am trying to verify a date that is in a spreadsheet created with Apache POI. When I do a `System.out.print` the Date variable and the cell contents are the same. Why is the test failing?

```
@Test
public void testSpreadsheetCont() throws Exception {
    Date date = new Date();
    boolean success = false;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("File Location.xls");
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
    HSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    HSSFRow row1 = worksheet.getRow(2);
    HSSFCell cell0 = row1.getCell(0);
    System.out.println(cell0.getDateCellValue());
    System.out.println(date);

    if (cell0.getDateCellValue() == date) {
        success = true;
    } else {
        success = false;
    }
    Assert.assertTrue(success);
}
```

I think that the error is how I am formatting the date in the class that generates the spreadsheet. There it is formatted as `("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")`. But when I format the date variable to `("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")` and try to compare the two elements it's unsuccessful.

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
if (cell0.getDateCellValue().toString() == ft.format(date)) {
    success = true;
} else {
    success = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use following for comparison. Perhaps this may be the reason.

```
if(cell0.getDateCellValue().compareTo(date)==0){
    success = true;
    }else{
        success = false;
    }
```

Comment: No, not yet. I added a  note to the top where I think the error is.

Comment: if 
    System.out.println(cell0.getDateCellValue());   and   
    System.out.println(date);
is still giving the same output, my suggestion is convert both in string and then compare it..

if(cell0.getDateCellValue().toString().equals(date.toString()))

Comment: Thank you for your help Sankumarsingh! :)                         Solved by creating new date formatted as                                             Date date = new Date("07/15/2013 00:00");                                                               Then compared with your toString sugesstion, if(cell0.getDateCellValue().toString().equals(date.toString())).

Answer (score 2):

No wonder it does not work because you are comparing two Date references - you will always get false there.